# How can I set the user state to null?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

I am using VueX within Nuxt and Typescript. I would like to have the initial state of my user be null. Setting `state.authenticatedUser:null` works fine. But once I try to asign a IAuthenticatedUser to it, it won't know the type since I assigned null and it will throw an error in my mutation where I put the comment.

So how can I have my authenticatedUser be null initially?

```
import { getAccessorType, mutationTree, actionTree } from 'nuxt-typed-vuex';

import IAuthenticatedUser from '~/ts/interfaces/firebase/user/authenticated_user.ts';
import * as counter from './counter';

type RootState = ReturnType<typeof state>

export const state = () => ({
    authenticatedUser: {} as IAuthenticatedUser, //I want this to be null
})

export const getters = {

}

export const mutations = mutationTree(state, {
    setAuthenticatedUser(state, newValue: IAuthenticatedUser) {
        state.authenticatedUser = newValue // If state.authenticateUser == null I cannot asign newValue becuase state.authenticateUser has a type of null
    },
    logOut(){
        state.authenticatedUser = null; // I cannot do this since it not of type IAuthenticatedUser
    }
})

export const actions = actionTree(
    { state, getters, mutations },
    {
        async onAuthenticationStateChangedAction({ commit, dispatch }, { authUser, claims }) {

            if (!authUser) {
                commit('logOut');
                return
            }

            const { uid, email, emailVerified, displayName, photoURL } = authUser

            commit('setAuthenticatedUser', {
                uid,
                email,
                emailVerified,
                displayName,
                photoURL,
            })
        }
    }
)

export const accessorType = getAccessorType({
    actions,
    getters,
    mutations,
    state,
    modules: {
        counter,
    },
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a class for the state that initializes it to null and declare `state` to be of that class should work

```
export class RootState {
    authenticatedUser: (IAuthenticatedUser | null) = null
}

export const state: RootState = {} as RootState;
```

`authenticatedUser` will then be `null` until you assign to it

```
state.authenticatedUser = {} as IAuthenticatedUser
```

Since the type is declared to allow null, you should also later be able to assign null again.

```
state.authenticatedUser = null
```